# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 crashes when opening web page

Tags: visual-studio-2010

As the title says, my Visual Studio 2010 SP1, running on Windows 7 x64, is crashing whenever I try to open a .html, .aspx, .cshtml, etc. file. I noticed this problem some weeks ago. Since then, when I open one of these kinds of files, it opens, freezes for a few seconds and then crashes. I tried using the repair function provided with the installer, but it didn't work. The only solution right now is to reinstall the os, but I don't feel like doing such thing.
Has anyone else encountered this kind of problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having this problem when using the default Web Form Editor and still haven't found a solution that works. I haven't a clue what's causing it, and the only plugin I have is Resharper.

I solved it temporarily by right-clicking the `ASPX` file, clicking `Open with` and choosing `HTML Editor` as the Default editor. Seems to be a problem with the Web Form Editor for a certain kind of files.